# How do I trigger multiple pis with one button?

Tags: gpio, camera

I currently have 4 Pi's, soon to have 40. I have them setup to take a picture when a signal is detected via GPIO. Individually they work.

I connected the pins on all 4 to one wire, and the grounds on all 4 to another wire. Then connected the wires and only one took a picture. I then broke it down and added one Pi at a time. Up to 3 worked, but the forth one threw it off again.

The weirdest thing is, I took the pin from the 4th Pi off the chain, and tried to get the first 3 to work again, and only the 4th Pi took a picture... Even though its ground was the only thing connected Where am I going wrong here? How can I trigger them all with one button?

[image: current wiring]

Comment: No reason why this shouldn't work.  Could you edit your post and include a diagram showing how the button is connected to the Pis?

Comment: I've added a basic diagram. It's a very basic setup.

Comment: You need to show the button.  Does it just connect GPIO21 to ground when pressed?  Are there any pull-ups to hold GPIO21 high when the button isn't pressed?

Comment: I see, There is no physical "button" I physically connect the wires, then disconnect them.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't time sensitive on the snapshots, maybe have one pi create the dir if not exist then add check if exists and a sleep to the rest to allow the directory to be created.

I would also add a diode to all the positive lines on each pi to prevent each pi from backfeeding a false trigger.

Comment: I changed it so one creates the directory if it doesn't exist. The others save it to the sd then move it to the directory after its created.

Comment: Hope that works out for ya. If it does could I get the honor of the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Joining the pins to one button doesn't appear to be the issue. The issue is in my script that was creating a directory if it did exist. The problem was all 4 trying to make a directory if it didn't already exist, and one would see that the directory didn't exist, and try to create the directory, but another pi beat him to the punch.

Comment: Does this mean the question has been resolved?

Comment: Yes, it was a coding error that became more likely to happen with each additional pi.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest adding a pullup/pulldown resistor or some other pullup/pulldown mechanism. I suspect having different power supplies for each Pi has something to do with this. Also, I don't see any pullup/down resistors in your diagram.

A quick search would result in a simple pullup/down circuit (i.e. just add a resistor between GPIO and ground **for each Pi**).

**An alternative would be to do it programatically since the Pi's GPIO pins can be pulled high or low in-software.** This would be the most practical option.

Take note that you may or may not have to change your trigger logic. For example, for a pullup setup, detecting a `low` would mean the button was pressed. For a pulldown setup, detecting a `high` would mean a button press. I'm sure you get what I mean.

I also suggest getting an actual switch/button since manually connecting wires can almost always cause issues with bouncing, unless proper debouncing logic is implemented (in software and/or hardware).